# Boostrap not working on WAMP server

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My html, css and bootstrap look fine when I view them on my MAC in chrome and safari. However, when I view it on the WAMP server (Windows XP pro) the Bootstrap does not seem to be implementing. The CSS seems like it still works fine.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/Users/Pat/Downloads/bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Website_Layout.css">  
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
          <li><a href="Website.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="Team.html">Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Safron Technologies</h1>
        <p>Social Media Application Specialists</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fuel">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>What Fuels Us?</h1>
        <p>We love building apps that change the way media is processed and viewed. Our apps will change your everyday life.</p>
      </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="learn-more">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h2>Development</h2>
            <p>We specialize in creating IOS Apps with the sole purpose of connecting people, products and ideas.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h2>Innovation</h2>
            <p>Safron Technologies is on the cutting edge of Social Media Application Development. We have the knowledge and experience to produce sucessful worldwide applications.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="nav2">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <p>(610) 639-7475</p>
            <p>safrontechnolo.g@gmail.com</p>
          </div>  
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2>Inside Safron</h2>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="Team.html">Team</a></li>
              <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>  
          </div>  
        </div>  
      </div>
    </nav>

  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: top;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  color: #FF6600;
  background-color: white;
  height: 60px;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url("/Users/Pat/Documents/Safron_Mountain.jpeg");
  height: 880px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FF7F50;
  text-shadow: -1.2px 0 black, 0 1.2px black, 1.2px 0 black, 0 -1.2px black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Shift',sans-serif;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.fuel {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #FF7F50;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.fuel h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 68px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: .3px .3px 0 #CCC, .6px .6px 0 #CCC, .9px .9px 0 #444, 1.2px 1.2px 0 #444, 1.5px 1.5px 0 #444, 1.8px 1.8px 0 #444;
}

.fuel p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.learn-more {
  height: 800px;
  margin-bottom: 0;

}

.learn-more h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 225px;

}

.learn-more p {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.nav2 {
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url("/Users/Pat/Downloads/footer_lodyas/footer_lodyas.png");
}

.nav2 h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.nav2 p {
  color: white;
}

.nav2 ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav2 a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;

}

.nav2 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  color: white;
}

.nav2 h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

Thanks for all of the help.

Answer (score 1):

`/Users/Pat/Downloads/bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/` is a path in your Mac computer and not in your Windows computer.

So you can choose to just have the file in the same folder (and use the file's name instead, as you did for `Website_Layout.css`) or use a [Bootstrap CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

Comment: That path IS a Windows path and certainly NOT a Mac path, but you are correct that it will not be accessible by the web server

Comment: @DavidG I am using a Mac and I have a path like that. But anyhow, I changed my answer a bit to specify what I mean.

Comment: Either way it's not relevant to mention Windows/Mac in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I like using relative paths in development so that I can move the files without any problems.For example, I create css,js and images folders inside the project directory.From there the path to say css files will be css/css_file.css.
Also,as mentioned by others you can use a  cdn like http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css.